# Efficiently page query results

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have mongo hooked up to a web application (Python/Pyramid Framework) and there is a large collection I want to display in the browser.  Since it is very large, I only want to render 100 records at a time, allowing the user to click a "load more" button to retrieve the next 100 records.  Pagination, essentially.

However, the documents have to be retrieved in descending order of an integer score that could be 0-100.  With more than 100 documents, there are multiple documents that have the same score.  So paginating would be a little trickier than just getting the next 100 documents that have a score less than or equal to the last one retrieved.

What would be awesome is if I could just save the cursor, so when the next 100 are requested, the cursor can just start from where it left off.  I'm trying to avoid just doing `query.skip(x).limit(100)` because I have read that is not very efficient since it basically retrieves all the documents you skip anyway.

But if I am retrieving documents based on sorting a non-indexed field, I don't know how much less efficient the skip/limit method would be, if at all.

I know there are a lot of other options I could pursue here, and feel free to mention them, but I am also genuinely curious if something like this is at all possible.

PS I have tried `pickle.dumps`... Doesn't work.

Comment: So do you just need to "load more" and move forwards in the results or do you need to reference numbered pages? Skip and Limit are required for the latter but if you need only "load more" then there is a more efficient way. The title detracts from your intent here.

Comment: The first one.  I need to move forward in the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forgive the JavaScript here, but it does serve as an example that can be reproduced in the shell for everyone and I'm working though this quickly. The essential points are basically the same in any language.

Consider the following documents:

```js
{ "_id": 1, "score": 2 }
{ "_id": 2, "score": 2 }
{ "_id": 3, "score": 5 }
{ "_id": 4, "score": 4 }
{ "_id": 5, "score": 5 }
{ "_id": 6, "score": 3 }
{ "_id": 7, "score": 1 }
{ "_id": 8, "score": 2 }
```

Now for the example here the results are going to be sorted descending by "score" and limited to "pages" of 2 results at a time. The initial query would then be issued like this:

```js
var seenIds = [];
var lastScore = 0;

var cursor = db.sorted.find({}).sort({ "score": -1 }).limit(2);
cursor.forEach(function(doc) {
    printjson(doc);
    if (doc.score != lastScore)
        seenIds = [];
    seenIds.push(doc._id)
    lastScore = doc.score;
});
```

The output would be from the sorted results:

```js
{ "_id" : 3, "score" : 5 }
{ "_id" : 5, "score" : 5 }
```

So the essential idea is that you iterate through the cursor doing whatever procesing you have to, such as output a stream or build up the content of another variable. As you iterate you want to store an array of the "unique" `_id` values that were seen in the last page of results. You also keep the value of the sorted field that is present. To make this optimal, you only need to keep as many "unique" `_id` values in there as were present for the current value of the score that is last "seen".

Of course these variables will need to be stored between requests such as in session storage. So do that so you can fetch them on the next request.

On any subsequent "load more" request you would then issue with an altered query as follows:

```js
var cursor = db.sorted.find({
    "_id": { "$nin": seenIds }, "score": { "$lte": lastScore }
}).sort({ "score": -1 }).limit(2);
cursor.forEach(function(doc) {
    printjson(doc);
    if (doc.score != lastScore)
        seenIds = [];
    seenIds.push(doc._id)
    lastScore = doc.score;
});
```

Noting that at the input states for those variables from storage will look like:

```js
seenIds = [ 3, 5 ];
lastScore = 5;
```

So the output of the query is:

```js
{ "_id" : 4, "score" : 4 }
{ "_id" : 6, "score" : 3 }
```

Now those new state variables in session storage will contain different values:

```js
seenIds = [ 6 ];
lastScore = 3;
```

And the get "load more" request uses those to get:

```js
{ "_id" : 1, "score" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 2, "score" : 2 }
```

So as you see the heart of this is when sorting by something such as "score" the general idea is to only retrieve those items that are either "less than or equal to" ( in descending order ) to the "lastSeen" value that was retrieved in the page.

Of course there is the potential that many items may have the same "score" value, so in order to counter this you keep a list of the "unique id's" that have already been seen for that same matching score value.

The query selection basically says, "get be all results with a score less than or equal to the value I last saw, but exclude anything I have already seen from the results.

Doing this allows for an efficient way of "forward only paging" through results without the `.skip()` and `.limit()` overhead. For optimal performance, make sure you actually "index" the field that is being sorted on as well.